# Use CASE THEN in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables which I want to query in MySQL as follows:

Table Notes

```
id  | note
-------------------
1   | note 1
2   | note 2
```

Table Indices

```
id  | name
-----------
1   | height
2   | weight
3   | other
```

Table Detail

```
  note_id    |  indices_id |  value
-------------------------------------
    1        |     1       |   50
    1        |     2       |   60
    1        |     3       |   20
    2        |     1       |   40
    2        |     2       |   10
    2        |     3       |   50
```

I need to query the result as follows:

```
  indices.name    |  note_id = 1 |  note_id = 2
------------------------------------------------
    height        |     50       |   40
    weight        |     60       |   10
    other         |     20       |   50
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT i.name,
(CASE WHEN d.note_id = 1 THEN d.value END) as Col2,
(CASE WHEN d.note_id = 2 THEN d.value END) as Col3
FROM notes n,indices i,detail d
WHERE n.id = d.note_id AND i.id = d.indices_id
GROUP BY i.name
```

But Column `Col3` result is `null`
Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: It's a pity that MySQL allows the use of a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions. It's best to pretend to yourself that it doesn't

Comment: The query is invalid and MySQL should raise an exception. Instead it silently applies `ANY_VALUE` on your expressions, thus arbitrarily picking either the value you are looking for or null. Try `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'`, so that MySQL doesn't allow such invalid queries anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an aggregation function so that you don't get random row data on `Col2` and `Col3`. `MAX` will work as it will ignore `NULL` values when the `note_id` doesn't match. Also, you should use explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT i.name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN d.note_id = 1 THEN d.value END) as Col2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN d.note_id = 2 THEN d.value END) as Col3
FROM notes n
JOIN detail d ON n.id = d.note_id
JOIN indices i ON i.id = d.indices_id
GROUP BY i.name
```

Output:

```
name    Col2    Col3
height  50      40
other   20      50
weight  60      10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j8wLBBdbGfZ4cfzhajtbsS/0)

Comment: @Ajax: Please see the joins in Nick's query. The comma-separated joins you were using in your original query were made redundant in 1992. I wonder how you even got the idea to use them. Don't. If you are using a book or tutorial or are attending a class teaching you so, quit it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of Nick's answer.  The `JOIN` to `nodes` is superfluous:

```
SELECT i.name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN d.note_id = 1 THEN d.value END) as Col2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN d.note_id = 2 THEN d.value END) as Col3
FROM detail d JOIN
     indices i
     ON i.id = d.indices_id
GROUP BY i.name
```